# border image syntax produces skewed image

Tags: css, border-image

I am not understanding the syntax of the border-image CSS function.

The following CSS works to produce the border in the correct place and width, but the image itself is badly skewed. It's not stretched (as in the CSS property) but it is compressed or some other mod that I don't clearly understand.

```
#page-header{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0px 30px;
-moz-border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 30 0 round;
-webkit-border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 30 0 round;
-o-border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 3 0 round;
border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 30 0 fill round;
}
```

The image itself is a simple Celtic knot that I want replicated in a single line across the bottom of the page header, meaning 'round' or 'repeat' across the x-axis but no transformation or replication across the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for border image looks different between browser prefixes.

Try the following:

```
#page-header{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 30px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 30 0 round;
       -moz-border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 30 0 round;
         -o-border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 30 0 round;
            border-image: url(test.png) 0 0 30 0 round;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... that didn't alter anything. I am assuming that something is occurring along the y-axis but I might be wrong.